# largest raspberry pi cluster

Tags: cluster

To my knowledge the cluster built by GCHQs is the currently the largest one. Does anyone know of a larger cluster currently being created? I found a 300 Pi cluster being built by this group http://megarpi.inf.unibz.it/index.php/about-us

Answer (score 5):

We can't really tell since anyone (including me) might have already built a 5000-node cluster and simply did not publish their work.

The largest one that's made aware to the public is, in fact, the GCHQ cluster.

Update: [This(link)](https://resin.io/blog/what-would-you-do-with-a-120-raspberry-pi-cluster/) is bigger.

<sub><sup><sub><sup><sub><sup>I might have a 10,000 node Pi 3 cluster in my secret Pacific ocean underwater lair. Muhahahahahha!</sup></sub></sup></sub></sup></sub>

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/magpi/seemore/ this one is bigger.

Answer (score 1):

[this](https://www.extremetech.com/extreme/259553-750-raspberry-pi-mini-computers-turned-supercomputer-los-alamos-national-laboratory) is bigger at 750 raspberry pi 3s at 3000 cores total

Answer (score 0):

Not strictly Raspberry Pi cluster, but still a huge 1 million ARM cores cluster to simulate the human brain.
https://www.zdnet.com/article/million-core-arm-machine-aims-to-simulate-brain/